# Are Covariance Operators based on square integrable stochastic Processes semi-positive definite?

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, integral-operators

Given a $\textbf{square integrable stochastic process}$ $X$ with $E\left(X\left(t\right)\right)=0$  $\forall t $ the $\textbf{Covariance Operator}$ is defined by
\begin{align}
  C_X: L^2 \rightarrow L^2
\end{align}
with 
\begin{align}
C_X\left(f\right)\left(t\right)&= \int Cov\left(X\left(s\right),X\left(t\right)\right)f\left(s\right) ds \\
&= \int E\left(X\left(s\right)X\left(t\right)\right)f\left(s\right) ds.
\end{align}
The operator $C_X$ is a $\textbf{Hilbert-Schmidt Operator}$ on the Hilbert-Space $L^2$.
I have read several times, that 
\begin{align}
  \langle  C_X\left(f\right),f  \rangle_{L^2} = \int \int  E\left(X\left(s\right)X\left(t\right)\right)f\left(s\right) f\left(t\right) ds dt \overset{!}{\geq} 0  \,\,\,\,\, \forall f\in L^2. \tag1
\end{align}
Thus $C_X$ is a $\textbf{non-negative operator}$ and has $\textbf{non-negative eigenvalues}$. 
I don't understand why (1) is greater than 0. Can anyone give a $\textbf{proof}$ or a $\textbf{counter example}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that 
$$
C_X(f)(t)f(t)=f(t)\int E\left(X\left(s\right)X\left(t\right)\right)f\left(s\right) ds
$$
and integrating, we get 
$$
\langle  C_X\left(f\right),f  \rangle_{L^2} =\int C_X(f)(t)f(t) dt=\int f(t)\left(\int E\left(X\left(s\right)X\left(t\right)\right)f\left(s\right) ds\right)dt
$$
hence inserting $f(t)$ in the inner integral, we get (1). This can be rewritten as 
$$
\langle  C_X\left(f\right),f  \rangle_{L^2}  =\iint   E\left(f\left(s\right)X\left(s\right)f(t)X\left(t\right)\right) dsdt
$$
and assuming that we can switch the expectation and the integral, we get 
$$
\langle  C_X\left(f\right),f  \rangle_{L^2}  =   E\left(\iint f\left(s\right)X\left(s\right)f(t)X\left(t\right)dsdt\right) 
$$
and the double integral in the right hand side is $\left(\int f(s)X(s)ds\right)^2$.